# How internally Hibernate set the generated ID(Primary key) which is in the database into the saved object?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

POJO class:

```
package com.hibernate.POJO;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private int sId;
@Column(name="NAME")
private String sName;

public Student(){
}

public int getsId() {
    return sId;
}
public void setsId(int sId) {
    this.sId = sId;
}
public String getsName() {
    return sName;
}
public void setsName(String sName) {
    this.sName = sName;
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
package com.hibernate.Test;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.hibernate.POJO.Student;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student st=new Student();
    st.setsName("Bishal");
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s=sf.openSession();
    System.out.println(st.getsId());//Here the O/P is 0
    s.save(st);
    System.out.println(st.getsId());//Here the O/P is value of Generated ID
    s.beginTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

Console:

```
0
Hibernate: insert into Student (NAME) values (?)
1
```

Here my question is that before saving the object we are getting the o/p for System.out.println(st.getsId()); is 0 which is the default value of int. After saving the object into database i.e. s.save(st); returns the generated id of the inserted row. I want to know that after saving how the object i.e. st have the generated id, is hibernate setting the sId value for that object i.e. st? How hibernate gets to know the generated id value which is in the database? Is there any data flow between hibernate and database to get the generated value , if it is then how data flow is happening between Hibernate and Database?

Comment: See [`Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

Comment: My question is not how to retrieve the auto generated id value from database  . My question is how hibernate gets the generated id value automatically from database and when and how setting that id into the saved object. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Through the JDBC api I indicated.

Comment: It retrieves the auto generated id value through the indicated JDBC api and calls the `setsId()` method with this value

Comment: @ThomasKläger you want to say that After inserting the row in the database, Hibernate use the JDBC API and calls the setId() method with the generated id internally without executing any extra query to get the generated id value. Is hibernate calls the getGeneratedKeys() method through JDBC API to get the generated id value?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: It's worth noting that inserting the row ***also*** happens through the JDBC API.